# how do i pass the HTTP response from one activity to another activity in android

Tags: android

In my application whenever i make a  HTTP post it gives HTTP response as JSON. but i want to parse this json in another activity. so how we pass HTTP response  from one activity to another activity in android.

Comment: pass the string values through `Bundle` get it in next activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent i =new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);

i.putExtra("json", jsonobject.toString());

startActivity(i);
```

In the new Activity you can get your json data like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent != null) {

        String json = intent.getStringExtra("json");
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        }
```

Comment: @ Kartheeki Jampana Welcome

Answer (score 1):

Intent i =new Intent(firstactivity.this,secondactivity.class);

```
            i.putExtra("Response", jsonobject.toString());

            startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity

Intent intent = getIntent();

```
 if (intent != null)
   {

        String Response= intent.getStringExtra("Response");
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as Bundle

```
object.putString("key",jsonobject.toString());
```

or as a shared preferences

---

new edited ans :
intent.putExtra(...);

Comment: intent extras.. `intent.putStringExtra(...)`

Comment: putExtra method sorry for that :'(

Answer (score 0):

You have different methods but the simplest is to put the JSON as extra in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_JSON", jsonString);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in NextActivity:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String json = extra.getString("EXTRA_JSON")
```

Answer (score 0):

In first activity
1. convert the jsonobject to String 
 2. And then put the string to intent

intent.putExtra("jsonString",theString);

Oncreate method of  next activity,

String jsonString = getIntent().getExtrz().getString("jsonString");
Log.i(" log "," json "+ jsonString);

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SharedPreferences` Store the json in shared preferences and you can retrieve the json through out the app in any number of activities. There is no need to pass the bundle to the another activity every time.

Example :

`SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("name",0);`

and use `Editor` to save the json in the shared preferences

`Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.put(key,value);`

and use the key to get the json from shared preferences from any activity of the app

`String json = pref.getString(key,defValue)`